# Too many re-renders. React Limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop - React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm writing a block of code to sort some data using React hooks. But I get the above mentions warning/error Below is my code.

```
const [sort, setSort] = useState(sortedInfo)

if (condition){
 // some logic
} else if (columns.find((col) => col.hasOwnProperty("actualSort"))){
 const {data, asc} = columns.find((col) => col.hasOwnProperty("actualSort").sorting)
 setSort(data);
}
```

My else case gets called many times which is fine as per the condition. Anything that can be done, so that setSort calls are minimized?

Comment: Change your `condition` or the `else if` test so that it doesn't run so frequently? Hard to say without more code context and without a description of the logic you're looking for

Comment: Don't call `setSort()` directly in the body of the functional component. Based on what I can see, you probably want to move that logic into a `useEffect()` callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling setSort() in render triggers too many renders,  use `useEffect` hook to trigger changes when value changes.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (condition){
    // some logic
  } else if (columns.find((col) => col.hasOwnProperty("actualSort"))){
    const {data, asc} = columns.find((col) => col.hasOwnProperty("actualSort").sorting)
    setSort(data);
  }
}, [condition]); // Only re-run the effect if condition changes
```

Comment: Probably want `columns` in the dependencies list as well.

Answer (score 1):

setState causes component re-render; and the re-render runs setState again - infinite loop;
In Functional components, must use useEffect to fix this problem;

```
useEffect(() => {
   setSort(data)
}, [condition])
```

`setSort()` caused the re-render, and then (if the condition is not changed) `useEffect()` makes sure `setSort(data)` is not running again.

Answer (score 0):

`setSort` will call re-render. So, it call If condition. You should use logic of if condition in function call or `useEffect`.